# I get the below when I run the below error when I run npm install && npm run dev

Tags: laravel

3 WARNINGS in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 3 warnings

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can then start writing an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [mre] to improve it before submitting it.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at this  [issue](https://npm%20install%20autoprefixer@10.4.5%20--save-exact)

```
npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact
```